# Required field validator for a check box outside a GridView

Tags: gridview, field, validation, required

I have couple of tabs placed in a .aspx page, in one of the tab i have a GridView. Now i need to add a checkbox under the Gridview and make it as a mandatory field i.e when try to navigate to other tabs it should not allow and show show a required field message. How can i achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use FindContrel. For example:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkID");
if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
 {
   // Your code ..............
 }
```